# Is "some other thing" as correct English as "something else"? If so, is there a difference between them?

Tags: comparison

I've just realized that I often say *some other thing*, instead of *something else*.

The latter seems the correct one, but I'd like to confirm this.

Furthermore, if the former was correct too, I'd be curious to know if there's a clear difference between the two, beside the way they are spelled. For instance, with reference to the sentence

*"If this goes wrong, then you'll have to try **some other thing**"* vs *"If this goes wrong, then you'll have to try **something else**"*

- is one "more correct" than the other?
- does *some other* imply/require an inherent difference between the current alternative and the *other* alternative(s), whereas *else* doesn't imply that?

Comment: Could you tell us the sentence where you use them? A couple of examples would be good.

Comment: To me, "Something else" would be by far the most natural way of saying this. If a native speaker were to say "some other thing" I'd assume they were specifically using an uncommon phrase for emphasis somehow (though I'm not sure how it would work without an example). Technically there's nothing wrong with it though, but I'd say definitely not idiomatic.